# Violación de segmento (`core' generado), lectura array bidimensional

Tags: c, bucles, array-bidimensional

Tengo un menú donde las primeras opciones es llevar acabo la lectura de matrices 3x3, pero cuando comienza la lectura me da "Violación de segmento ('core' generado)"
Aquí la parte del código que les comento.
¿Como se podría solucionar?¿A qué se debe esto?
Después tengo que operar con las matrices pero eso es lo de menos, lo que necesito es que pueda hacer la lectura de los arreglos

```
int main(){
int A[m][m], B[m][m], C[m][m];
int op, i, j;

do
{
    system("clear");
    printf("\tTarea 7\n\nMenú");
    printf("\n1. Leer A\n2. Leer B\n3. Leer C\n4. Asignar 0 en A\n5. Asignar 0 en B\n6. Asignar 0 en C");
    printf("\n7. Asignar 1 en A\n8. Asignar 1 en B\n9. Asignar 1 en C\n10. Obtener A transpuesta");
    printf("\n11. Obtener B transpuesta\n12. Matriz Identidad en A\n13. Matriz Identidad en B\n14. Matriz Identidad en c");
    printf("\n15. A+B\n16. A-B\n17. A*B\n18. Imprime matriz A\n19. Imprime matriz B\n20. Imprime matriz C\n21. Salir\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);   
}
while(op<1 || op>21);

switch(op)
{
    case 1:
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Lectura de datos de A\n");
                printf("\nInserte el dato de la matriz A en la posición (%d,%d):   ", i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d", A[i][j]);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Lectura de datos de B\n");
                printf("\nInserte el dato de la matriz B en la posición (%d,%d):   ", i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d", B[i][j]);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Lectura de datos de C\n");
                printf("\nInserte el dato de la matriz C en la posición (%d,%d):   ", i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d", C[i][j]);
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Encontré el error, me falta '&' en la parte de la lectura de las matrices jajaja, que tonto :p

Comment: Por favor, borra entonces la pregunta ya que la misma carece de sentido